# Case Properties saved in one app and referenced in another via case sharing

Tags: commcare

I would like to know to display a case property in a case shared application, when it was saved into a different application on the same project space.

I referenced it with #case/caseproperty, but it doesn't seems to work.

The case type is the same and the property has a value when I review the case in CommCareHQ.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Hi Juan, this sounds a bit like it is a bug in the CommCareHQ form builder. Can you report an issue to the developers for them to follow up on?

Comment: I found that the problem got resolved by activating the case ownership in the locations structure.

Answer (score 1):

Juan, unfortunately that's a limitation of easy references in the form builder.

There is a work around:

1. Add a case property that does exist in the app to your form
2. Turn off easy references in the form builder
3. You'll notice that your #case/myproperty changes into something that looks a little complicated (instance('casedb')/casedb/case[@case_id = instance('commcaresession')/user/session/case_id]/mycaseproperty
4. Just edit that complicated expression and change "mycaseproperty" bit at the end to whatever case property you want to access
5. Turn easy references back on in the form builder